# Are there outdoor formaldehyde detection systems available?

Tags: gas, motion-sensor

We have a nearby factory polluting air with formaldehyde and when the wind occasionaly brings it to us we sense the smell and are forced to close the windows to not let it in. When the wave subsides we can open the windows again. It would be convenient to have an outdoor sensor giving an alarm when the level starts rising to give us time to close the windows before it starts to get in and notifying us when the level is back to normal so that we can open the windows again.

Are there such solutions available on the consumer market? I know there are industrial solutions but those are expensive and not available to individuals.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is a VOC (volatile organic compounds) monitor or a IAQ (indoor air quality) monitor. They do exist for residential applications and are way much cheaper than the industrial counterparts; however, their detection/sensitivity level may not be as great.

You can try your luck by searching for "iaq monitor" on Amazon and eBay. Prices may vary and be sure to research the product a little, some may only detect CO and other "gases" (LPG, propane, and etc.) and may not make any mention of formaldehyde.

Once you find the right monitor, you will probably have to install on the inside of your home near the window you usually leave open. I don't think these monitors were made to be placed outside.